# Changing a variable with keys in Python

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

This code I wrote just destroys the entire project (line 15 to line 22). I tried other formatting but nothing works. Here's my code:

```
import turtle
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

screen = Screen()  
PenWidth=input("Enter your Penwidth, you can later adjust it with k and l")
jack = Turtle("turtle")
jack.color("red", "green")
jack.pensize(PenWidth)
jack.speed(0)

def up():
    jack.setheading(90)
    jack.forward(100)
def Pensmaller():
    global PenWidth
    PenWidth=-2
    jack.pensize(PenWidth)
def Penbigger():
    global PenWidth
    PenWidth=+2
    jack.pensize(PenWidth)


turtle.listen()

turtle.onkey(up,"Up")

turtle.onkey(Pensmaller, "k")
turtle.onkey(Penbigger, "l")

screen.mainloop()`
```

Comment: What exactly are you having problems with? Is it an error?

Comment: You need to be more informative, I'm afraid. Tell us exactly what error it is you're receiving, show us your error logs etc.

Comment: For the first function add Jack as a param or make it global

Comment: @IsmailHafeez That doesn't matter at all.

Comment: @IsmailHafeez SanjaySuresh is right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You typed the operators in the wrong order. You should change the `Pensmaller` and `Penbigger` functions as follows:

```py
def Pensmaller():
    global PenWidth
    PenWidth -= 2
    jack.pensize(PenWidth)

def Penbigger():
    global PenWidth
    PenWidth += 2
    jack.pensize(PenWidth)
```

In your original code, you used `PenWidth=+2`, which sets `PenWidth` to `+2`. To add to a number, the plus sign must come before the equal sign, e.g. `+=` instead of `=+`. The same with `=-` which has to be `-=` to subtract from the number. Additionally, to avoid an TypeError and to be  able to add to / subtract from it, convert the PenSize at the beginning to int, like so:

```py
PenWidth = int(input("Enter your Penwidth, you can later adjust it with k and l"))
```

Comment: Your solution doesn't work. Here is the Error message I get every time I press a key (in this case k):

Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1884, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/turtle.py", line 687, in eventfun
    fun()
  File "/Users/gian/Desktop/TigerJython/Paint.py", line 67, in Pensmaller
    PenWidth -= 2
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'str' and 'int'

Comment: @Zwiebelgian i edited my answer with a fix for that, should work now